# VTK C++ set points for vtkStructuredGrid from three XYZ vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vtk

VTK examples uses `vtkPoints` to set coordinates for the structured grid. Usually it works as
`points->InsertNextPoint(i, j, k); structuredGrid->SetPoints(points);`
But my XYZ coordinates are stored in three different vectors `x, y, z` and I don't want to copy them as it takes a lot of memory, how can I set coordinates for structured grid directly from XYZ vectors without copying?

Best regards,
kerim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VTK also supports Structure Of Arrays.

```
  vtkSOADataArrayTemplate<double>* pointArray = vtkSOADataArrayTemplate<double>::New();
  pointArray->SetNumberOfComponents(3);
  pointArray->SetNumberOfTuples(nbOfPoints);
  pointArray->SetArray(0, XArray, nbOfPoints, false, true);
  pointArray->SetArray(1, YArray, nbOfPoints, false, true);
  pointArray->SetArray(2, ZArray, nbOfPoints, false, true);

  vtkNew<vtkPoints> points;
  points->SetData(pointArray);
  pointArray->Delete();
  VTKGrid->SetPoints(points);
```

Comment: How should we create the XArray, YArray, and ZArray in this case? I try to create them in this way:`vtkNew<vtkDoubleArray> XArray;`
but there is error `cannot convert 'vtkNew<vtkDoubleArray>' to 'vtkSOADataArrayTemplate<double>::ValueType*' {aka 'double*'}
   33 |   pointArray->SetArray(0, XArray, nbOfPoints, false, true);` Thanks!

Comment: oh, this works `(double*)(XArray->GetVoidPointer(0))` if I create XArray by this way `vtkNew<vtkDoubleArray> XArray`